# diffChangeLog not generating modifyDataType

Tags: liquibase

I have modified my entities `login` field from

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String login;
```

to

```
@NotNull
@Email
@Size(min = 5, max = 254)
@Column(length = 255, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String login;
```

When I look at the changelog generated by using `diffChangeLog` the modified data types are not generated. Is it not supported? Can any one point me in the direction? I went through the forums and internet to see but all it shows is the xml but not the generation part.

Comment: The annotations are applied by hibernate (I am assuming you're using hibernate). When you change them hibernate will generate new tables based on your changes.
Liquibase `diffChangeLog` command runs from the already changed database and then generates your changelog. You should read about how liquibase works!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. New to Hibernate and liquibase. I have previously worked in Python/Django but had to move. Learning one by one. Is there a way to generate those or do I have to do them manually.